# React Native + Spring Boot + WebSocket

Tags: java, spring-boot, react-native, websocket, spring-websocket

how can i setup websocket between react native and spring boot. this works if you use html+js, but it doesn't work with react native.

spring config class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/websocket").setAllowedOriginPatterns("*").withSockJS();
    }
}
```

spring controller class

```
@Controller
@CrossOrigin("*")
public class WebSocketController {

    @MessageMapping("/hello")
    @SendTo("/topic/greetings")
    public Greeting greeting(HelloMessage message) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(message.getName());
        return new Greeting("Hello WORK, " + message.getName() + "!");
    }
}
```

react native component

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { View, TextInput, Button } from 'react-native';
import SockJS from 'sockjs-client';
import { Stomp } from '@stomp/stompjs';
import { TextEncoder } from 'text-encoding';
global.TextEncoder = TextEncoder;

const Test = () => {
    const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
    const [stompClient, setStompClient] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const socket = new SockJS('http://192.168.1.234:8081/websocket'); 
        const client = Stomp.over(socket);

        const connectToWebSocket = () => {
            client.connect({}, () => {
                setStompClient(client);

                client.subscribe('http://192.168.1.234:8081/topic/greetings', (message) => {
                    console.log('Received message:', message.body);
                });
            });
        };

        connectToWebSocket();

        return () => {
            if (stompClient) {
                stompClient.disconnect();
            }
        };
    }, []);

    const sendMessage = () => {
        if (stompClient) {
            stompClient.send('http://192.168.1.234:8081/app/hello', {}, message);
            setMessage('');
        }
    };

export default Test;
```

I tried several libraries, but nothing worked for me (

I need to try to set up a connection using the topic

how can i setup websocket between react native and spring boot. this works if you use html+js, but it doesn't work with react native.

Comment: please check your ip address. That must be ipv4 address of your computer in your network. Secondly, please check internet access for react native android manifest.

Comment: yes, it is correct. i used ipconfig

Comment: can you check this project please, maybe helps to you: https://github.com/gurkanucar/qr-login-mobile